# SQL Case to Sum

Tags: t-sql

I am grouping products based on customer, reporting back how many we have in stock and their condition code.  The condition code we're using is not what we want to report back, so I am using CASE to change this.  There is one product that has a blank value in the condition code.  This product is showing twice, once with a condition code of A (quanitity 7100), and once with a condition code of blank (quantity 4).  I need to group by using the condition code as well, as we could have the same product in different conditions.  For any blanks, I need to include them to be an A.  Using CASE to change the blank to an A reports the product twice, one with 7100 and one with 4.  I need to sum these two together.  Here is the code I am using currently.

```
SELECT  CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, SUM(QUANTITY) as 'On Hand',  
        CASE (RESERVED)
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'H'
            WHEN 'I' THEN 'L'
            WHEN '0' THEN 'A'
            ELSE RESERVED
        END AS 'COND_CD'
FROM    binlocat    
GROUP BY 
        CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, RESERVED
ORDER BY 
        PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeat the `CASE` in the `GROUP BY` or perform the substitution then sum;

```
;WITH T(CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, QUANTITY, RESERVED) AS 
(
    SELECT CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, QUANTITY,
        CASE (RESERVED)
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'H'
            WHEN 'I' THEN 'L'
            WHEN '0' THEN 'A'
            ELSE RESERVED
        END 
        FROM binlocat
) 
SELECT CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM T
GROUP BY CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, RESERVED
ORDER BY PRODUCT
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had to also include WHEN ' ' THEN A in the first select statement.

Comment: Ah yes I thought `0` was your empty value

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your query like this:

```
SELECT CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, COND_CD, SUM(QUANTITY) AS 'On Hand'
FROM
(
    SELECT  CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, QUANTITY,
        CASE (RESERVED)
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'H'
            WHEN 'I' THEN 'L'
            WHEN '0' THEN 'A'
            ELSE RESERVED
        END AS 'COND_CD'
    FROM binlocat
)
GROUP BY 
    CLIENTNAME, PRODUCT, COND_CD
ORDER BY 
    PRODUCT
```

The inner `SELECT` creates a table on which the outer select can do the grouping.